# Does disabling Background App Refresh disable Push notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, apns, multitasking

I just got my iPhone, and before I make any default changes, I just wanted to make sure it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. This is a separate service and daemon on the device.